# Youtube cam Recording OverLay

Tags: javascript, php, flash, youtube, youtube-api

On my website, any registered user can record videos and upload them to Youtube, which is great and working very smoothly.

But I wanted to add an Overlay Image/Gif/animation above their own videos to represent my website, or just give them the ability to add some Effects on their videos without using my website resources (even a blank or overlay on their video for some seconds or the full length of the video with an image/animation "like a video" Effect, just like some pc softwares can do, such as webcamMax )

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by re-encoding the video using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) filters.

By executing `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2" output.mp4`, ffmpeg will place an image in the upperleft corner of the video.

Comment: sounds really amazing , but is there is a way to cover the whole screen too ?